# disable 250 character URL limit in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, url

Users of a SharePoint Document Library are getting this error:

> The URL for this file is too long for the application. A temporary copy of this file will be opened on your computer. You must save this copy as a new file.

After doing some [research](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/The+URL+for+this+File+is+Too+Long+for+the+Application+Due+to+Path+Limitation), it appears Internet Explorer has a limit of about ~250 characters for a URL.  Some URLs provided by SharePoint far exceed this limit.  One example being 790 characters long.

Is there a way to disable this limit?  I have looked, but there doesnt appear to be a solution, other than shortening the folder/path names.

Comment: Did you mean 250 characters or have I missed understood your question? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427. Any way, in case you didn't come across this, it *may* help: http://blogs.technet.com/b/seanearp/archive/2010/07/09/long-url-s-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: the 250 character limit appears to be limited to sharepoint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, looks like the answer is no.

> No, this is a hard limit in SharePoint. Studying the schema of the
>   content database reveals the limit originates from the primary key
>   columns DirName and LeafName in the AllDocs table.

The only way is to work around it by creating shorter names. They do offer a link to a tool to help (see source), but not sure if editing the filenames/paths is an option or not?

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341350/adjust-sharepoint-url-field-length)

Comment: But why should it have to do sth with Content DB Limits when for Chrome it is working?